# Drag control over flash movie issue?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, css, flash, z-index

I'm using jquery to drag popup control around the page ,every things work fine but when the page has flash movie the popup doesn't appear over flash also when set z-index to 100 .

is there any work around this issue???

```
$('.modalPopup').ready(function() {
$('.modalPopup').draggable({ zIndex: 2700 });
});
```

Comment: what is the z-index of the flash movie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this param to your `<object>`:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

Be aware that there *are* some issues with this solution (performance, handling hit areas, etc), but this may give you what you need.

Check out this handy [demonstration of different WMODEs](http://www.adamia.com/blog/visualizing-flash-wmode-options).